# How to prove that e^x is convex?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For convexity :

$$e^{ta+(1-t)b} \leq t \cdot e^a+(1-t)e^b
\Rightarrow e^{(a-b)^t} \leq te^{a-b} + 1 - t$$

Now I'm stuck on how to solve it further.

Answer (score 3):

Are you allowed to use derivatives? From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function): "A twice differentiable function of one variable is convex on an interval if and only if its second derivative is non-negative there".

Since the second derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, and $e^x > 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, we have that $e^x$ is convex on any interval.

Comment: I just want to solve it without using derivative. Can you please help ?

Comment: @user141256 At least *for me*, the exponential function is *defined* by the fact that it is its own derivative, namely as the unique(!) solotion of $f'(x)=f(x)$, $f(0)=1$. With that situation, using the derivative would be the *most direct* approach. There are of course other ways to define the exponential, and for each there may be another notion of "most direct" ...

Answer (score 1):

The exponential function is infinitely differentiable and hence you can apply the second derivative test which is a lot easier than the method you are employing. Assuming then that you are allowed to use the second derivative:

$$f \prime \prime (x) = e^{x}>0$$

and you see that this is a (strictly) convex function on any interval.

Comment: I just want to solve it without using derivative. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly know that $e^x$ grows faster and faster and that it is always positive. Can you conceive a curve satisfying the first condition without being convex ?